# Query for handling valid numeric

Tags: t-sql

How to get valid value from the following query

```
SELECT Answer FROM table 
WHERE values LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Basically I want the data can deal for

1. 28,000 (valid)
2. $20000 (valid)
3. Annual Amount (invalid)
4. ? (invalid)
5. 28.00 (valid)

Thanks

Comment: The 'values' column is of type char/varchar yea? If so, this is more of a regex question.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be a little more precise as to what you mean by valid and invalid. Are you looking for something that can be interpreted as a unitless decimal value in US format, or else a dollar amount in US format, with no extra text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Answer
FROM table
WHERE 
    ISNUMERIC(values)
    OR (
        SUBSTRING(values, 1, 1) = '$' 
        AND ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(values, LEN(values) - 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
select replace(replace(values, '$', ''), ',', '') as number from table
  where dbo.RegexMatch(values, ^\$?(\d+|(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+))(\.\d+)?$')
```

tweak the regex to match any conditions you need...